# Configurando o Dominio com o Google Compute

Tags: google

Tenho uma máquina virtual no Google Compute Engine com Wordpress e tenho um registro cadastrado no Registro.br.

Quero registrar meu domínio no Google Compute, porem não estou tendo sucesso. Alguém sabe qual o procedimento?

Comment: Lembre-se que a resposta do Raffael precisa de cuidados. Quando for criar o IP estático, lembre-se de atribuir a Virtual Machine. Caso contrário, será cobrado do Google Cloud o uso desse IP que não está atribuído a nada.

Answer (score 3):

1. No Google Cloud, entre no Console.
2. No menu lateral, clique no item "Redes".
3. Entre em "Endereços IP Externos", localize a instância que deseja e crie um endereço estático para ela.
4. Copie esse endereço estático (externo).
5. Clique em "Cloud DNS" no submenu lateral.
6. Crie uma zona e entre na tela de detalhes dela.

   6.1 - Na lista de registros NS, copie dois dos endereços e informe os mesmos no "registro.br" como DNS Master e Slave, respectivamente.

   6.2 - Nessa mesma tela (detalhe de zona), clique em "Adicionar Conjunto de Registros" e adicione um registro do tipo "A".

   6.2.1 - No campo IPv4, informe o endereço de IP estático (externo) de sua instância desejada criada no Compute Engine.

Opcional: dentro da sua instância (compute engine), configure seu servidor/proxy conforme seu domínio/subdomínio.